# How to verify which is primary node in a HANA DB cluster operating on SLES 12?

Tags: suse, cluster, sles, replication, failover

Currently I have two HANA DB servers in a cluster and replication is not running. Upon checking from SUSE Hawk, node 2 is acting as primary node and node 1 is available. How do I confirm that node 2 is primary?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

try as `sidadm` (where `sid` is your SID).

```
cd /usr/sap/sid/HDB000/exe/pyhton_support
python systemReplicationStatus.py
(lines with service, site name, secondary site name, etc ...)

Local System Replication State
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

mode: PRIMARY
site id: 1
site name: MOON_SID
```

lasts line will tell you

- if you are primary/secondary
- in `site name` line , `moon` is your hostname

you might also parse result of `crm_mon -1R` (as root)

Comment: Replication is not running at the moment and the output shows this system is not a system replication site. Hope you could advise

Comment: Hello @Fabian19 I am afraid no, HANA replication is beyond my scope. I guess you have some sort of external support or higher level internal support avaiable.